# Figure out where decimal point goes when dividing floats as integers

Tags: python, python-2.x, division

I'm wanting to make a script that can perform maths on large numbers while keeping the precision as high as required. I attempted ones ages ago and division was the worst part by far, so I thought I'd try start with it this time.

Basically, I'm using `str` inputs, as they obviously remain perfectly accurate, and I'd like to perform calculations on them as integers so that nothing is lost to floating point numbers. I'm doing that currently by removing the decimal point before the calculation, then trying to re-add it, but I can't figure out how.

With multiplication, you can figure out the decimal by adding how many numbers are left of the decimal point in both numbers. Unfortunately that method doesn't seem to work with division. I previously tried coding long division, but again it's an awkward one if there's floats involved.

Here's the current code I've got, with some of the non working parts removed:

```
from __future__ import division


def _divide(a, b, precision):  
    count = 0
    while a and count < precision:
        for num in str(int(a // b)):
            yield int(num)
            count += 1
        a = a % b * 10

def divide(a, b, precision=100, round_int=True):

    result = []
    a = str(a)
    b = str(b)

    #Check for negative numbers
    a_neg = a[0] == '-'
    b_neg = b[0] == '-'    
    if a_neg and not b_neg or b_neg and not a_neg:
        result.append('-')

    #Process number strings
    a_split = a.split('.')
    b_split = b.split('.')
    try:
        a = abs(int(a_split[0] + a_split[1]))
    except IndexError:
        a = abs(int(a_split[0]))
    try:
        b = abs(int(b_split[0] + b_split[1]))
    except IndexError:
        b = abs(int(b_split[0]))

    #Calculate number
    result += list(_divide(a, b, precision=precision+round_int))

    if not round_int:
        return ''.join(map(str, result))


    #Round last integer
    last_int = int(result.pop(-1))
    index = -1
    if last_int >= 5:
        try:
            result[index] += 1
        except TypeError:
            index -= 1
            result[index] += 1

    #Lower any integers above 10
    while True:
        if result[index] == '.':
            index -= 1
        if result[index] > 9:
            result[index] -= 10
            if result[index-1] == '.':
                index -= 1
            result[index-1] += 1
        else:
            return ''.join(map(str, result)).rstrip('.')
        index -= 1

a = '365.72'
b = '2247.7'
print divide(a, b, 9, False)
print float(a) / float(b)
```

I just drew up a quick hacky way which uses the inbuilt float division to figure out where the decimal is, but obviously it's not ideal as it'll fail after `1e300`:

```
cheat_div = str(abs(float(a) / float(b)))

if 'e' in cheat_div:
    num_decimals = int(cheat_div.split('e')[1])
    if num_decimals > 1:
        num_decimals += 1
else:
    if cheat_div.startswith('0.'):
        num_decimals = 2 + len(cheat_div[2:].lstrip('0')) - len(cheat_div)
    else:
        try:
            num_decimals = cheat_div.index('.')
        except ValueError:
            num_decimals = 0
while not result[is_negative]:
    del result[is_negative]

if num_decimals:
    if num_decimals > 0:
        result = result[:is_negative+num_decimals] + ['.'] + result[is_negative+num_decimals:]
    else:
        result = result[:is_negative] + ['0', '.'] + ['0'] * -num_decimals + result[is_negative:]
```

Comment: If you want it easy, use the `decimal` module :-P

Comment: No fun in having it too easy haha, though my plan is to store the exact numbers (eg. multiply the denominator when doing a divide), so if nobody replies I guess I could be lazy with this since it's not a super important part :)

Comment: You can also find out how the decimal module is solving this issue.

Comment: What you're asking for is impossible. `1/3` is two numbers of only a single digit each, but how many digits will the result require?

Comment: Well the idea is for the class to store 1 and 3. if you divide by 5 then it changes to 1 and 15 and so on. The division is just the final step to display which would ideally be able to handle any size numbers. Out currently but I'll have a peek at the decimal source code later :)

Comment: In that case you probably want the [`fractions` module](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fractions.html).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, cheers. That only appears to support integers but it looks like it has a couple of functions that will come in really useful